# Trying to Center An Img In A Div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center an img in a div without success and I have tried many CSS hacks. I'm missing something and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

**Markup**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="row">     
    <div class="col-md-4" > 
      <div class="img-guarantee">  
        <img src='img/clock.png' class='img-responsive'> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.img-guarantee img{ 
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

Comment: Remove the `display: inline-block` and simply add `text-align: center` to the parent.

Comment: @MitchelJager: text-align only works on inline elements.

Comment: `<img>` is inline by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, using a column outside a row is not advised whatsoever. I take it that you use Bootstrap so it's only appropriate to use a column within a row.

Secondly, you can create another class by the name `.text-center`, add the CSS rule: `text-align: center;` and finally add the newly created class to the parent element which in this case is `<div class="col-md-4">`

This is the final result: https://jsfiddle.net/ydeeLLrd/1/ (including a fix to the first issue)

Comment: I just want to say that you can use the class `.text-center` in any parent element you want so that you don't have to re-type the same CSS rules every time for every element. It's handy.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```css
.img-guarantee img{ 
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 
 .img-guarantee {
   text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="row">     
  <div class="col-md-4" > 
   <div class="img-guarantee">  
     <img src='img/clock.png' class='img-responsive'> 
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```